# many very confusing problems with kinetic.js

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

i got some problems with understanding kinetic.js (the documentation is horrible for newbies...) i hope i can explain it with my bad english.

Problem 1: Everytime when i #reset my canvas it is not really resetting it. its more like its pushing another background image over the actual canvas and when i click on it it jumps back to the original...

```
function clearCanvas() {
context.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);   //whole canvas
context.drawImage(buehneObj,0,0);      //redraw the main background image
}
```

and call it with:

```
reset = document.getElementById('reset');
document.getElementById('reset').onclick =function(){clearCanvas();
}
```

Problem 2: the slider i build for scaling the image is not working at all but i dont see the problem... ...the variables are global and if i test alert it i see that values are existing...

standard jquery slider:

```
$('#scaleslider').slider({
        animate: "fast",
        step: 0.1,
        value: 1,
        min: 0.1,
        max: 1,
        slide: function(event,ui){groesse = ui.value} //global variable
});
```

i made it hidden(display:none) and on click "block"

```
var scaleslider = document.getElementById('scaleslider').style;
document.getElementById('resize').onclick =function(){ scaleslider.display ="block";}
```

and here's how kinetic parts look like (dragMotiv is my first start image) "groesse" is the variable for my x and y slider value(they can us the same so it scales correct):

```
var dragMotiv = new Kinetic.Image({
      image: imageObj,
      x: 250,
      y: 300,
      width: 330,
      height: 263,
      rotationDeg: 0,
      scale: { x:groesse, y:groesse },
      draggable: true,
      dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {

        var newY = pos.y < 290 ? 290 : pos.y > 305 ? 305 : pos.y;
        var newX = pos.x < 250 ? 250 : pos.x > 390 ? 390 : pos.x;
        return {
          x: newX,
          y: newY
        };
      }
    });
```

Problem 3: Saving is not possible at all.

i uploaded it to my server to let you guys take a look at it. i know that there is one little thingy that i just dont see(i hope so).

http://manufaktur13.de/playground/canvas_kinetic.html

Comment: Please try to include the specific portions of code that you think cause the problem for easier reference.

Comment: added some code, hope that helps. thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not clear the canvas, instead you should keep record what you have drown and remove those items, and redraw the layer.